# Why did the family in Fear the Walking Dead give up so easily?

Tags: the-walking-dead, fear-the-walking-dead

In the second, and most recent, episode of *Fear the Walking Dead*, the main characters are preparing to flee Los Angeles to the desert, where they hope to wait out the crisis.  This seems strange, because they have had very little contact with the zombies.

The heroin addict son has seen two zombies, one of which his mother and stepfather also saw.  The mother, stepfather, and daughter saw a video of an incident involving a third zombie.  Late in the second episode, the mother encounters a fourth zombie.  The daughter's boyfriend has been bitten, but is alive.  No one knows what is going on yet.

And yet, before the mother ran into the fourth zombie, she was stealing OxyContin and large amounts of canned food from the high school where she is a guidance counselor, which is the kind of thing that you don't do unless you are absolutely certain that you will never need to work again - stealing a student's prescription opiate painkillers is an incredibly serious offense.

It has been roughly three days since things started to get weird, and it was only the second day when the stepfather said "That's it, we're going to hide in the desert for an indefinite period of time".  At that point, they had only seen one zombie in person, and another one on a YouTube video.

Why did this family give up and run away so quickly?

Comment: Maybe they watched The Walking Dead.

Comment: @Voldemort - I don't think so. Technically, the first two episodes of *Fear the Walking Dead* take place before the first scene of the first episode of *The Walking Dead*, so there's nothing to watch.  Also, both the concept and the word "zombie" are unknown in the TV version of the *Walking Dead* universe.  Finally, from an out of universe perspective, the characters wouldn't be so surprised about the whole Inevitable Zombie Apocalypse if they had been watching *The Walking Dead*.  The first time they see a zombie, their reaction isn't "oh, look, a zombie", it's "WHAT IS THAT THING?!?"

Comment: Man that was a joke lol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personal experience.
In a situation where an  epidemic breaks out or where a civil war starts you dont want to be in the middle of the happening. You want to get the hell out of there as fast as possible and let the government sort that out.
They are afraid. Weird stuff is happening and the government isn't saying anything.

So there is going to be looting, chaos, lawlessness until the government can come back in and assert order again.

So they try doing the best thing for them. And that is to flee until the situation is normal again.

The kid in the episode said it. Looters will hit the pharmacies, the gun stores and the food stores. Police will try to contain the situation by locking the meds down. So mom does what is sensible. She takes meds from a source that isn't going to get locked down as a priority.

Having personally been in one civil war (Balkans in the 90s)I can tell you that food goes FAST!! So they are thinking ahead. 
We see that the infrastructure is starting to break down so it is every soul for themselves until order is restored.

Comment: I agree that they are doing the best thing they can, although it definitely isn't going to make much of a difference. The issue isn't what should be done, but rather, how does this family know what to do, and why did they do it so quickly?  But the mother was already stealing prescription drugs before the kid mentioned that pharmacies were being looted.  I don't understand why a random family led by an English teacher and a guidance counselor is so on the ball.

Comment: Well being in the employ of the county they prob have some kinds od disaster plans. so the mother tries the doctor and when the tepephones dont work she does the only other sensible thing to help her child. And that is to steal that wich she has easy access to! They might not be on the ball but they do have a heads up that others maybe dont. also Desperation! that leads ppl to do crazy things. And a mother that is desperatwe to save her chils will go above and beyond every single time when put in the situation.

Comment: agree as well.. food, meds n bullets are a must have in zombie scenarios.. or else your brains gonna end up in some zombie's platter..

Comment: @RicoRicochet - The problem is that no one in this world knows what zombies are, or what's going to happen.  We know, of course, but the characters don't.  This is a completely new experience for them.  Kirkman has even said that, unlike the comics, on the show, the characters live in a world where zombies don't exist as fictional entities.  That's why no one on the shows refers to them as "zombies" - that word doesn't exist.

Comment: genre blindness.. cliched..

Comment: @WadCheber I hate universe rules that serves no purpose other than for the mechanics of the story. Like *Buffy the Vampire Slayer*'s universe didn't have cell phones so warnings about danger or betrayal couldn't be prevented by a text message. That's just plain lazy.

Comment: @zer00ne - I don't see any analogy to TWD in your example.  The comics are in a world where zombie movies exist.  The show is in a world where they don't exist.  It isn't lazy at all, it's just different.  Every story employs elements that are solely intended to facilitate the development of the plot.  That's not a bad thing, it's just part of writing a story.

Comment: @RicoRicochet - See my previous comment.

Comment: @WadCheber People in general, local, and federal governments, institutions, etc. would be slow to react regardless of whether their culture had zombie media, mythology, or whatever you'd call it. Good writing wouldn't need excuses and exclusions, good writing can integrate with the audiences' experiences and perceptions with the story. If the story happened to be on a colony on the moon and 100 years into the future, then yeah go nuts and exclude zombie media, cell phones, and automobiles for all I care. Some see it as an enhancement, I see it as a crutch.

Comment: @zer00ne it's worth pointing out that Buffy was started in the late 90's, well before cell phones and texting were ubiquitous.  I don't think that was bad writing, unless you're singing them on failure to predict the future

Answer (score 3):

She wasn't actually stealing food, but helping Tobias take the food. And the fact that both of them left the food after she killed Artie indicates they are in panic mode, which makes people do strange things. I am telling you, if I didn't know about zombies and I saw someone I knew (ie. Calvin the drug dealer) rise from the dead, repeatedly, that would be enough for me to flee suburbia and head somewhere isolated to wait it out. Knowing how her son would react coming off heroin would also make me steal meds anyway I could in order to get him to a safer location before letting him come off them.

Comment: Helping someone else steal food is still stealing food.  :)

Comment: @WadCheber stealing food doesn't matter if it means you will survive until a bit longer.

Comment: @Cherubel - That's not the point.  The point is that she went from "nothing weird is going on" to "I'm going to steal from the place where I work" in about 10 minutes.  It just seems pretty abrupt.

Comment: @WadCheber I'm with Rachel.  If I saw the Calvin thing happen personally, I'd be out.  Especially taken in conjunction with the videos of shootings online, I would be taking zero chances.